# Removing chars on every line of string (C#)

Tags: c#, string

So I'm currently trying to remove the following chars: "# " (With the space) It kinda works, because I have 3 lines, and it removes it on the first line. Here is my code:

```
string serverInfo = "Connected to 74.91.119.188:27015\n" +
                            "hostname:[FN] 24 / 7 Surf Utopia | Styles | !KNIFE,!WS,!GLOVES\n" +
                            "version: 1.37.9.5 secure\n" +
                            "os      :  Linux\n" +
                            "type    :  community dedicated\n" +
                            "map: surf_utopia_v3\n" +
                            "players : 24 humans, 0 bots(64 / 0 max)(not hibernating)\n" +

                            "# userid name uniqueid connected ping loss state rate\n" +
                            "# 3785 1 \"Con\" STEAM_1:0:128083116 03:13 32 0 active 196608\n" +
                            "# 3786 2 \"yolo\" STEAM_1:0:172863146 03:13 171 0 active 196608\n" +
                            "# 3787 3 \"chodyツ\" STEAM_1:0:42129452 03:13 46 0 active 786432\n" +
                            "#end\n";
            var removeEnd = serverInfo.IndexOf("#end");
            var newString = serverInfo.Remove(removeEnd);
            var firstHashTag = newString.IndexOf("#");
            var secondHashTag = newString.IndexOf("#", firstHashTag + 1);
            var final = newString.Substring(secondHashTag);

            if (final.Contains("# "))
            {
                var index = final.IndexOf("# ");
                var newFinal = final.Substring(index + 2);
                Console.WriteLine(newFinal);
            }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Here is the output:

[image: Output]

My question is:

How can I apply this to every line, I don't know how many lines there will be, all I know is that I need to remove "# " from every line there might be. (I don't know how many there will be, this is just for practice)

Comment: Currently this string is assigned by you, why are the `#` and `\n` there if you don't need them. Another option you could use is a `StringBuilder`. IMHO, much of that code can be removed. `I don't know how many lines there will be` can you clarify then where and or how you are getting this string from?

Comment: So this is like getting data from an API, where I've just written the data I'm gonna get myself, because I currently can't get it from the API

Comment: I am confused, this isn't coming from an API right, this is just something you did? If this is the case most API's will return serialized data in json and or xml format, which then could be easily deserialize and used however.

Comment: The data would be like this, if it was from the API

Comment: In addition to what the others have mentioned- It looks like you have a few things you want to remove- I'd suggest implementing a rule engine pattern https://yiniski.medium.com/rule-engine-pattern-8a3f0e0c2d81 iterate over each line and pass them through the rule engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to remove all occurrences of "# "? Why don't you just use
`string newString = serverInfo.Replace("# ","");`

This outputs:

```
Connected to 74.91.119.188:27015
hostname:[FN] 24 / 7 Surf Utopia | Styles | !KNIFE,!WS,!GLOVES
version: 1.37.9.5 secure
os      :  Linux
type    :  community dedicated
map: surf_utopia_v3
players : 24 humans, 0 bots(64 / 0 max)(not hibernating)
userid name uniqueid connected ping loss state rate
3785 1 "Con" STEAM_1:0:128083116 03:13 32 0 active 196608
3786 2 "yolo" STEAM_1:0:172863146 03:13 171 0 active 196608
3787 3 "chodyツ" STEAM_1:0:42129452 03:13 46 0 active 786432
#end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something on a string line by line you should use `System.IO.StringReader` class:

```
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(yourMultiLineString)
{
     while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null){
         string line = reader.ReadLine();
         //do something on line here
     }
}
```

That's it, I left the implementation code to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code solution for your problem. Keep looping and removing until the index of remove string  is -1. Keep in mind that the function "Replace" works on the first value it finds.

```
var textToRemove = "#end";
while(serverInfo.IndexOf(textToRemove) > -1)
{
   serverInfo = serverInfo.Replace(textToRemove, string.Empty);
}
```